# Calculate the speed of transfer file in socket c#

Tags: c#, performance, sockets

I research a lot and I found a way to calculate it, but I'm not convinced 
Please help me how to fix it ??? :( 
That is my code

```
while (sum < length)
{
    stopWatch.Restart();
    if (length - sum > packetSize)
    {
        count = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, packetSize);
        Send(socket_File, buffer);
    }
    else
    {
        buffer = new byte[length - sum];
        count = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, length - sum);
        Send(socket_File, buffer);
    }
    stopWatch.Stop();
    sum = sum + count;
    SendFile.Downloaded = sum;
    SendFile.Transfer_rate = ((sum * 8) / stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds).ToString();//kbps
}
```

Comment: @motaz99 in all your questions you just say "help me fix it". It is better to actually tell us what is not working and what you expect.

Comment: @usr I do not know if this method is correct and if not I want to correct it.

Comment: @motaz99 then you are asking us to do your homework. We are not here to provide you a complete solution. We help you fix **specific** issues.

Answer (score 2):

Some random points:

- you probably want to sample clock outside of the loop, not on every iteration,
- some of the file reading time is also included in your calculations,
- you are measuring time of putting bytes into OS socket buffer, not actual transfer.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not convinced

Why not? Nobody can fix a problem until you identify it.

However your *copying* code is all wrong. You are assuming that the read fills the buffer. You cannot assume that with TCP.

```
if (length - sum > packetSize)
{
    count = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, packetSize);
}
else
{
    count = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, length - sum);
}
Send(socket_File, buffer, count);
```

And of course the stopwatch start and stop and printout should be outside the loop, otherwise you're just timing individual read/write pairs.

Comment: @motaz99 What 'show speed'? There is none in your code. Just some lines that calculate it, incorrectly.